# In which divisions of banking are the Greeks and Black Scholes equation applied?

Tags: black-scholes, greeks

I know that Black Scholes and the Greeks are important in market risk. In what other areas are they used?

Comment: Greeks are inherently risk measures, they cannot be used for anything else. Black Scholes is used for derivatives pricing of course.

Comment: They're also used to create financial crises in the European Economic Community, but that's a different type of Greek ;)

Comment: @barrycarter: that's more about credit risk then, I guess :)